# Java: variable names for a directory path, naming variables in general

Tags: java, string, file

I'm having difficulties to decide how to name a File variable and a String variable, which both describe the same directory.

Basically I have a String describing the location of a directory containing testcases. With this String I want to create a File object. Something like this:

```
String testcaseDirectoryPathString;
File testcaseDirectoryPath = new File(testcaseDirectoryPathString);
```

What I want to achieve is the most readability for my code, by choosing good variable names.

I searched the internet, but I end up finding naming conventions in general and the advice that variable names should be 'speaking'.

My question are for a specific examples, but my problem is not only with String and File naming but with choosing good variable names in general.

So here are some questions:

1. Is it good practice to add the word 'String' to any String object?
2. Is it good practice to add the word 'Path' to any File object?
3. Is it a matter of personal preference and there are no good practices?
4. How do you name your variabls and why?

If there are any articles out there, I would appreciate you pointing me to them.

Comment: I think this question is good, but better fits to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ I believe if you search there for 'naming conventions' you might find valuable answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's just my opinion:

1. **Is it good practice to add the word 'String' to any String object?**

No, it doesn't contribute. Just make the name longer without reason adding the type in the name.

2. **Is it good practice to add the word 'Path' to any File object?**

Same as nº1. You don't need the type in the name of the variable.

3. **Is it a matter of personal preference and there are no good practices?**

Always you need to follow a good practice coding to make it legible, have this in mind:

> “Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you live.” - John F. Woods.

And most important thing, try allways to follow the company naming standards, maybe they aren't the best but will help to make the code rideable.

4. **How do you name your variabls and why?**

I always try to name my variables with short names, specifying something important and following the lower camel case using english even working in a spanish company where is not mandatary. And as I said following the company naming standards.

`String testcaseDirectoryPathString;`

`File testcaseDirectoryPath = new File(testcaseDirectoryPathString);`

If I don't have another directory path maybe I use this:

`String directoryPath;`

`File <<something that describe the result file>> = new File(directoryPath);`

with `<<something that describe the result file>>` I means something like `prizeRepresentations`, `annualSales`, etc...

**OFF THE RECORD**
If you use eclipse you can see the plugins checkstyle and pmd, they will help you to have a clean and clear code and to get used to work this way.

Comment: I would like to upvote it twice for that John F. Woods. quote!

Answer (score 4):

*Is it good practice to add the word 'String' to any String object?*

No, it just repeats the type. Use names which express the meaning of variables.

---

*Is it good practice to add the word 'Path' to any File object?*

No, see above. Additionally it would produce confusion for any reader: Is the type of the variable `java.io.File` or `java.nio.Path`?

---

In your example I would change the following:

Rename `testcaseDirectoryPath` to `testcaseDirectory`
Rename `testcaseDirectoryPathString` to `testcaseDirectoryName`

Answer (score 1):

General guide is:

- be specific, if you read your field/variable name, get a clue what is it for, but don't overdo it. Always check it out with an eye of an outsider. Would you like to see and work with a field named businessRegulationSecondServiceFactoryInstanceFromASingleton? On the other end, never use one character field, variable, only if it is a very basic index for a loop.
- don't need to repeat the String since all IDE will help you out in determining the type.
- avoid negations if it is not neccessary, like 'boolean notDisabled' use 'boolean enabled'.
- keep your names tidy, and use recognizable patterns through your code, if anybody reviews your java files, at the second or third class, that person should get a picture of your programming style, what (s)he should expect on the other parts of your code.

Get guidance on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ there are numerous questions in this topic. Usually together with "good practice" and "naming conventions"